# Passenger tmp file not found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phusion-passenger

```
2015/06/08 18:15:07 [crit] 6450#0: *28773 connect() to 
/tmp/passenger.1.0.6428/generation-0/request failed (2: No such file or directory) 
while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.x.x, request: 
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.6428/generation-0/request:", host: "x.x.x.x"
```

From what I've found online, there's something erasing the tmp file but I have no idea what application is doing so.

Whenever I restart the app, it'll work fine which means tmp deletion is the issue.

Any idea what it could be or how I can find it?

Comment: Is that just a file or something like a socket? Can you do a `ls -l /tmp` to show it?

Comment: @ott-- The actual request file: `srwxrwxrwt 1 root     root        0 Jun  8 20:29 request`

Comment: It's a socket and I think the app itself deletes it.

Comment: @ott-- well nginx returns 503 error when it does delete it. Should I be altering nginx or passenger?